# UserDisplayName column is empty in the Comments table

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

The column UserDisplayName of the Comments table in Data Explorer appears to be empty.

[Demonstration](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328844/10-recent-comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [only populated in cases where the user doesn't exist](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/328846) on the target site, such as when the question is migrated to a site where the commenting user doesn't have a preexisting account, or the user is deleted.

Otherwise the username can be determined by linking to the users table on the `UserId` field.

Comment: Thanks. I should have realized that by analogy with OwnerDisplayName column in Posts, which works the same way.